# How to redirect to variable link after authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a notes app , where people can keep their notes save (using express).
I want to add google authentication and for that I'm using passport.

My routs are -

```
/notes/:userId  => for home page
http://localhost:8080/login/google/redirect => Authorized redirect URL
```

I'm also using a middleware `isLoggedIn` for checking if the user is loged in or not.
My middleware code -

```
module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
if(!req.user ){
    req.flash('error', 'User must be signed-In');
    return res.redirect('/login');
}
next();
```

}

In this I'm checking if the `req` have user property which passport atomatically adds while login using `passport.autheticate()` .
But now when i'm login using Google I need to use a fixed redirect URL. So how i redirect user to `notes/:userId` after authentication.
I tried using `req.redirect` in my redirect URL

```
router.get("/login/google/redirect", passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/register'}), 
async (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.user._id;
    res.redirect(`/notes/${userId}`);
});
```

but can't able to pass my middleware `isLoggedIn`.
How can I make this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use isLoggedIn as /notes/:id route's middleware.

```
router.get("/notes/:id" , isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    // your logics code
});
```

Comment: I'm using isLoggedIn in /notes/:id route itself my question is passport add user property in the route of the fixed redirect URL which I can't access in other route i.e /notes/:id